# OpenGeo Suite Dashboard not Showing Up on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: boundless-suite

I have installed OpenGeo Suite 3.1 on my machine (windows 7 64-bit) and I am encountering the following strange behaviour:
When I try to run the Dashboard, nothing appears! HOWEVER, the relative Process at the Task Manager, appears normally and is taking about 30MB of Memory!

Do you have any idea, what causes this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Desktop-based Dashboard sometimes just won't load, and we've never been able to properly diagnose the issue.

As a workaround, you can start OpenGeo Suite via links in the Start Menu, and then navigate to the web-based Dashboard:

```
http://localhost:8080/dashboard
```